# Merge two data frames by id and date

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have two data frames.
A:

```
id  date
1   2010-05-08
2   2012-08-08
3   2013-06-23
```

B:

```
id  date1
1   2010-05-09
2   2012-08-08
```

I need to left merge the two data frames by id and also where date in table 2=date in table1 +1 day. Further flag the row where the merge is TRUE.

The final output is
A:

```
id  date           date1      flag
1   2010-05-08    2010-05-09   1
2   2012-08-08       NA        NA
3   2013-06-23       NA        NA
```

The code to generate the data-

```
A <- data.frame(customer = c(1,2,3),
                application_date = c("2010-05-08", "2012-08-08", "2013-06-23"))
B <- data.frame(customer = c(1,2),
                application_date = c("2010-05-09", "2012-08-08"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

**DATA**:

```r
A <- data.frame(customer = c(1,2,3),
                application_date = c("2010-05-08", "2012-08-08", "2013-06-23"))
B <- data.frame(customer = c(1,2),
                application_date = c("2010-05-09", "2012-08-08"))
```

**DPLYR**:

```
library(dplyr)

    data <- left_join(A, B, by = "customer")
    data %>% 
      mutate(logic = if_else(as.Date(data$application_date.x) + 1 == as.Date(data$application_date.y), 1, 0)) %>% 
      rename("id" = "customer",
             "date" = "application_date.x",
             "date1" = "application_date.y",
             "flag" = "logic")
```

**Output**:

```
 id       date          date1         flag
 1       2010-05-08     2010-05-09    1 
 2       2012-08-08     2012-08-08    0 
 3       2013-06-23     <NA>          NA
```

**DATA.TABLE**:

```r
library(data.table)

data_2 <- merge.data.table(A, B, by = "customer", all.x=TRUE)
data_2[, logic:= (ifelse(as.Date(data$application_date.x) + 1 == as.Date(data$application_date.y), 1, 0))]
setnames(data_2, old = c("customer", "application_date.x", "application_date.y", "logic"), 
                 new = c("id", "date", "date1", "flag"))
```

**Output**:

```
 id       date          date1         flag
 1       2010-05-08     2010-05-09    1 
 2       2012-08-08     2012-08-08    0 
 3       2013-06-23     <NA>          NA
```

Comment: Thanks so much Eric.  Would you also be able to give the data.table code? I am new to R and I have been suggested to use data.table.

Comment: Updated my answer to include data.table.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont mind updating A directly by reference, here is an update join option:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(A)[, d := dateA + 1L]
setDT(B)
A[B, on=.(id, d=dateB), c("dateB", "flag") := .(dateB, 1L)]
```

data:

```
A <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3),
    dateA = as.Date(c("2010-05-08", "2012-08-08", "2013-06-23")))
B <- data.frame(id = c(1,2),
    dateB = as.Date(c("2010-05-09", "2012-08-08")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using data.table:

```
data <- merge(A, B, by = "customer",all.x = TRUE)
library(data.table)

setDT(data)
data[as.Date(application_date.x)+1==application_date.y,flag:=1]
data[as.Date(application_date.x)+1!=application_date.y,flag:=0]
data <- data[,.(id=customer, date=application_date.x,date1=application_date.y,flag)]
data
```

Comment: Thanks jnordeman.  I need to join by ID and also where it satisfies the condition, application date from tableB=application date from table 1 +1 day.